# How to manage multiple Google accounts via oauth2

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, google-api, youtube-api

In my web app, the user can connect with their YouTube accounts so they can access their Video Uploads and interact with them through the web application.  This works great for a single YouTube account.  Am struggling with how I can allow people to link multiple YouTube accounts without creating multiple accounts on my site.

Is this supported by Google's API?

Here is what I tried to do (using Python and Django) ... cut it down so it was a little more manageable.  Basically, I can't get Google to re-up and ask for a new authorization ... it seems to just know who the user is and respond.  Any help in any direction is appreciated.

```
# models.py
class YouTubeAccount(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    google_plus_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, editable=False, null=True)
    display_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)

class FlowModel(models.Model):
    id = models.ForeignKey(YouTubeAccount, primary_key=True)
    flow = FlowField()

class CredentialsModel(models.Model):
    id = models.ForeignKey(YouTubeAccount, primary_key=True)
    credential = CredentialsField()
```

Then in a view for adding accounts:

```
@login_required
def add_account(request):
    yt_acct = YouTubeAccount.objects.create(user=request.user)
    yt_acct.save()

    # i thought maybe I use the yt_account as my flow state
    FLOW.params['state'] = xsrfutil.generate_token(settings.SECRET_KEY, yt_acct)
    authorize_url = FLOW.step1_get_authorize_url()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(authorize_url)

@login_required
def return_authorization(request):

    yt_acct = YouTubeAccount.objects.get(user=request.user, google_plus_id__isnull=True, display_name__isnull=True)

    if not xsrfutil.validate_token(settings.SECRET_KEY,
                                    request.REQUEST['state'],
                                    yt_acct):
        return  HttpResponseBadRequest()

    credential = FLOW.step2_exchange(request.REQUEST)

    http = httplib2.Http()
    http = credential.authorize(http)
```

Comment: i have exact same scenario in my application. The problem i am having is,at the callback servley code, how do i identify which user(identified by a unique id) had initiated this google account link.so that i know to which user should i associated this account authorization. How did u manage that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they'll choose which account to use while authenticating, or they can just assign a default.
Here's more info: http://apiblog.youtube.com/2013/06/google-page-identities-and-youtube-api.html

But if you are asking one user to have multiple Google accounts, then you can ask them to go through OAuth again. And in each operation you can only use one user OAuth, so per each account, all aPI calls should be repeated. Here's PHP samples using client library. In these you can simple store into multiple json files etc, let them go through OAuth as many as they want.
https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/tree/master/python

Comment: It looks like, if I'm reading it correctly, that *one* Google Account can have multiple "Channels" ... effectively, different YouTube accounts.  So the user would have to set this up on Google's end first ... because what I was asking, initially, is how do I implement multiple Google Accounts? Does that make sense? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks you for the info - I used the python example to build the app for my user uploads.  The issue I am having is how do I force a user to re-up their oauth?  Just deleting the credential store doesn't work -- google re-initiates the user auto-magically.